# Изменение иконок в аккордеоне

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Сделал аккордеон, но не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы иконка ПЛЮС менялась на МИНУС при открытии блока, и обратно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<ul class="accordion-list">
            <li class="accordion-list__item">
                <h5 class="accordion-title">
                    <span class="title-icon plus"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <span class="title-icon minus"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    Как я могу пользоваться приложением</h5>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                    <p>Чтобы воспользоваться приложением "My BMW Remote" или "BMW i Remote", Вам необходимо в активировать функцию дистанционного управления в личном кабинете на портале "My BMW ConnectedDrive", выбрать контрольный вопрос и ответ на него.  </p>
                </div>
            </li>


$(function() {
        $(".accordion-title").on('click', f_acc);
    });

    function f_acc() {

        $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp(600);
        $(this).next().slideToggle(500);

    }
```

Comment: У меня постоянно показывается ПЛЮС, иконке МИНУС я добавил свойство display:none

Comment: В текущем варианте приведенного кода недостаточно. Добавьте фрагмент CSS со стилями, чтобы удалось воссоздать возникшую у Вас проблему